# not able to upload same image with ng-show and ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, image

I want to upload image to the server, I have two images, one on left side currently i am uploading other is previously uploaded image to the  right. left Side image will appear when user clicks the "Upload" button , after upload I have provided "X" mark to the right of the Image, after clicking "X" I hiding that uploaded image. Once again If I upload same Image which I uploaded earlier which is not uploading why? . If I upload  some other Image it is uploading.

```
 <div  ng-click="deleteLocalfile()" ng-hide="deletePreviewImage" ng-show="showImage" class="img-wrap">
  <span  class="close">&times;</span>
  <img   ng-src="{{imagepreviewUrl}}" ng-if="imagepreviewUrl"  style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="" data-id="103">
</div>
<a   ng-show="user.photo.photoProof" href><img ng-src="{{tabindexUrl}}" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt=""></a>
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">
  <span>Upload</span>
  <input  data-flow-btn type="file" ng-model="user.photo.photoProof" name="photoProof" id="photoProff"  class="upload"/>
</div>`<div class="list-group mt-md mb-0"  data-ng-show="$flow.files.length" data-ng-repeat="file in $flow.files">
  <div class="box-layout list-group-item" data-ng-hide="fileUploadSuccess">
    <div class="col-xs-2 va-m">
      <span class="img-wrapper img-rounded" style="width:50px;"><img imageonload="onImgLoad('photo')" flow-file-added="validate($file)" flow-img="file" alt="" style="width: 50%; height: auto;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 va-m">
      <div class="progress progress-sm nm">
        <div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{width: (file.progress() * 100) + '%'}"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 va-m"><strong>{{file.name}}</strong >  {{file.size}} bytes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Controller Code:

```
 $scope.onImgLoad = function(type){
  $scope.deletePreviewImage = true;
  $scope.previewImageUrl = '';
  switch (type){
    case 'photo':
      MyService.getBase64Content($scope.flow.photoDoc.files[0].file, function(e){
        $scope.user.photo.photoProofContent = e.target.result.substr(e.target.result.indexOf(',') + 1);
        $scope.imagepreviewUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ $scope.user.user.photoProofContent.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
        $scope.previewImageUrl = $scope.imagepreviewUrl;
        $scope.deletePreviewImage = false;
 });
```

deleteLocalfile method:

```
$scope.deleteLocalfile = function(){

$scope.showImage = false;
      $scope.deletePreviewImage = true;
```

}

After Image Upload say "1.jpeg"   it will appear as left as side Image , after clicking "X" on this image, it will hide , later If I upload same Image say "1.jpeg" I am not able to load its not calling  $scope.onImgLoad() method, If I upload some other Image say  "2.jpeg"  it is appearing as left side Image. why "1.jpeg" not coming?  the src attribute in image tag holding previous image, its not changing why?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when uploaded one file and upload the same file again, browser won't trigger change event。 So before uploading the same file , you need set input's value to empty string. For example, $('#photoProff').val('');

I don't reading your code carefully , if you provide a codepen url address or jsFiddle url address, I can know more.

Comment: hey thanku so much for telling about browser wont trigger change event when we upload same  file . Used this code on input element later works onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onImgLoad('photo')" .

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution for you is - Use ng-if instead of ng-show or ng-hide.

ng-if will load element in html only when condition is ture, else not. whereas in case of ng-show or ng-hide , only display of image is set to block or none respectively, but image is always in DOM.

Example

```
<img ng-src='someurl' ng-if="condition==true" />
```